# Elastic Search Storage Purging in local

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

I know if we've installed ES on Linux, the default data folder is in /var/lib/elasticsearch (CentOS) or /var/lib/elasticsearch/data (Ubuntu).

My question is

1. Whether the ES does any purging internally.If it does, what will the interval and size it does.
2. Also when hitting thruough api, it will give records from any date or any restriction on that too ?

Please answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all the data is kept indefinitely. You will have to delete an index manually or use a tool like Elastic Curator or Index Lifecycle Management to remove data automatically.

Deleting lots of individual documents from an index is not recommended, because the following merge (that will actually free the disk space) will be quite expensive.

All the data that is currently stored can be searched. Though any filters (to limit the searched timeframe for example) will help to speed up search operations.